# Python Selenium CSS Selector by Span get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, timeoutexception

I have already accessed a webpage, populated text boxes and drop downs with required parameters, and submitted (button click) this information so the webpage can perform a calculation.  I am trying to access the results (value of text). Results should be a list of calculations listed least to greatest, and I only want the lowest value.  I am not sure if I am having a timing issue or a CSS Selector issue.

I have tried:

```
e = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[data-bind='calc']")
new = e[0].text
print(new)
```

Error: IndexError: list index out of range

I wanted to make sure the data table was being completely populated before I tried to access it's calculated elements, and I have also tried:

```
output_by_css = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.calc')
)

for output in (output_by_css):
    print(output.text)
```

Error: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Can someone please help me determine if this is an issue with the CSS Selector by span or if it's a timing issue, or something else I have not yet thought of? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why the selector is different in the second case. Should not it be `span[data-bind='calc']`?..

Comment: I am not sure if the selector is correct, I have been trying multiple things.  The HTML is <span data-bind="text: calc"> … </span>, and the unique selector is .table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1).  I don't know if CSS is even the best type of selector to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try applying the following selector:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span[data-bind*=calc]')
```

Here we are getting all the `span` tags having `data-bind` attribute having "calc" inside the value.

Comment: This does not work with the first attempt, because I was having a timing issue and a selector issue.  Changing the selector to get all span tags works perfectly in the second attempt though. Thanks @alecxe